# Deduction guide with type alias after ->

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Take a look at [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/4nx9uy):

```
template<class T>
struct S {
    template<class U>
    S(U) {}
};

template<typename T>
using SP = S<T*>;

// template<class U>
// S(U) -> S<U*>;

template<class U>
S(U) -> SP<U>;

S s(0);
```

Unfortunately, it is rejected by Clang:

> ```
> error: deduced type 'SP<U>' (aka 'S<type-parameter-0-0 *>') of deduction 
>        guide is not written as a specialization of template 'S'
> S(U) -> SP<U>;
>         ^~~~~~~~~~
> ```

ICC rejects it either with a similar error:

> ```
> error: the return type must directly designate a specialization 
>        of the associated class template
> ```

However, GCC and MSVC both compile this code.

Which compiler is right? After all, a type alias is just an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang and ICC are correct here: the restriction on how to name the template and type is [phrased syntactically](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#3.sentence-3).  C++20 allows “class template” argument deduction for alias templates, but does not support (separate) deduction guides for them.